# Dynamic selection of data frame

Tags: r

I have several data frames (or actually xts objects) that are named x_10min, x_h, x_d, x_w, as they have different time steps (10 minutes, hours, days, weeks). I would like to dynamically select the data frames in a simple for loop. Can I do this? How? I only find information on how to dynamically select columns, but I want to select the whole data frame.

Here is an example of what I have tried so far.

```
timestep <- c("10min","h","d","w")
for (ts in 1:4) {
   x_mod <- SOMEFUNCTION???(paste("x_", timestep[ts], sep=""))
   # ...
   # and then I use x_mod in my model
   # ...
}
```

Comment: Why don't you store these dataframes in a list, and called them via the list ? E.g. `my_list[[paste("x_", timestep[ts], sep="")]]`

Comment: This is new to me, will take a look! With a first try it seems like it could work as fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `get` function

```
timestep <- c("10min","h","d","w")
for (ts in 1:4) {
   x_mod <- get(paste("x_", timestep[ts], sep=""))
   # ...
   # and then I use x_mod in my model
   # ...
}
```

Comment: While this works, it’s almost always a better idea to do what Cyril’s comment suggests.